# a2enmod doesn't work on Mac OS X - Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, apache

I have a little problem with "a2enmod" under Mountain Lion.
I startet apache with "sudo apachectl start" and tryed to load passenger with

```
a2enmod passenger
```

but i throws:

```
-bash: a2enmod: command not found
```

Apache is working correctly at my localhost... any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

a2enmod is a command to enable an Apache module. You can achieve the same thing by editing `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and explicitly adding the passenger module:

`LoadModule passenger_module libexec/apache2/mod_passenger.so`

More about `a2enmod` here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2084284?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 25):

a2enmod was written for the Debian distribution, as it is a Debian-specific script with the package.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a CLI tool for enable/disabling Apache modules called the Apache Module Manager. It is cross-platform and best of all works on macOS.

For example:

```
$ amm enable passenger
$ amm disable passenger
```

Check it out at https://github.com/kodie/apache-module-manager